# Parallel testing a Jenkins with specific tests from a maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, thucydides

I currently have a maven project with ~500 tests. These are webdriver test with the Thucydides framework. There are several types of tests such as swiping tests, article link tests, sharing tests, etc.

Details of the current setup:
* Selenium
* Thucydides
* Jenkins

I would like to run parallel tests in Jenkins but I want each jenkins job to only run a specific type of test. Is there anyway of using the "Goals and options" in the Build section in jenkins job configuration page to only run a specific type of test i.e. run only the swiping tests? or are there other options available?

Ideally I Would like to run separate jobs for each type of tests and run in parallel all those jobs together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to achieve it purely in Jenkins, but the first option coming to my mind is that you could create separate maven profiles for each test type and create one jenkins job per profile.

For more info on maven profiles, see official docs: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks for the help @peter-butkovic. My colleague found a really cool solution that you might be interested in. You can tag your tests with `@WithTags` e.g. `@WithTag(type="feature", name="login")` and then you can test all test with those tags by using the following command `mvn test -Dtags="feature:login"`. This is a great way to test a specific bunch of tests.